# strange segfault using template as parameter

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I have a sorted list, which takes a Comparator as parameter. In a unit test I tried to use two different comparators.

The strange thing is, using the `StringReverseComparator` with the two if-statements disabled (commented out), all works well and valgrind does not claim any error.

```
template<typename T> class Comparator {
public:
  virtual int compare(const T * left, const T * right) = 0;
  };


class StringReverseComparator : public Comparator<String> {
public:
  int compare(const String *left, const String *right) {
    int rv = strcasecmp((const char *)*left, (const char *)*right);

    if (rv < 0) return 10;
    if (rv > 0) return -10;

    return rv;
    }
};


class StringComparator : public Comparator<String> {
public:
  int compare(const String *left, const String *right) {
    return strcasecmp(left->operator const char*(), right->operator const char*());
    }
};
```

As soon as I enable both if-statements, I get a segfault from sort method.
Sort method is the standard qsort by sedgewick.

`const char *` is an operator from `String` class to access the character array.

First I thought, that changing the comparator might cause troubles, so I created a new instance of sorted list. But that traps too as soon as I have the two if-statements enabled.

So what's wrong with the compare method?

//edit:

Ok, first the sort code (taken from sedgewick):

```
template<typename T> class SortedList {
public:
  // rest omitted

protected:
  void sort() { qsort(0, _size - 1); }
  void qsort(int left, int right) {
    if (right > left) {
       const T *v = _elements[right], *tmp;
       int i = left-1;
       int j = right;

       for (;;) {
           while (_comparator->compare(_elements[++i], v) < 0) ;
           while (_comparator->compare(_elements[--j], v) > 0) ;
           if (i >= j) break;

           tmp = _elements[i];
           _elements[i] = _elements[j];
           _elements[j] = tmp;
           }
       tmp = _elements[i];
       _elements[i] = _elements[right];
       _elements[right] = tmp;
       qsort(left, i-1);
       qsort(i+1, right);
       }
  }

private:
  int               _size;
  const T         **_elements;
  Comparator<T>   *_comparator;
};
```

... and here the `operator char *`.

by the way: String class passed all unit tests and was ok with valgrind too.

```
class String {
public:
    // rest omitted

  operator const char   * () const { return _s; }
  const char * operator * () const { return _s; }

private:
  char    *_s;
};
```

about usage of `strcasecmp`: my first attempt was:

```
return strcasecmp( ... ) * (-1);
```

using the same parameters as in `StringComparator`. When that failed, I tried anything I could imagine about, including the if-statements and different call syntax of `operator char *`.
`strcasecmp` does not return just -1, 0, 1 - as mentioned in many tutorials. The return value differs in size and sign and after -1, 0, 1 failed to, I tried using 10. The value has no significance, could be 815 or 42, what ever.

// edith 2

Thanks you all for your attention!

I solved it myself. The point is, the qsort algo was not safe enuf :(

The following sort code works fine (with any kind of comparator):

```
void qsort(int left, int right) {
  if (right > left) {
     const T *v = _elements[right], *tmp;
     int i = left-1;
     int j = right;

     for (;;) {
         while (++i < _size && _comparator->compare(_elements[i], v) < 0) ;
         while (--j > 0 && _comparator->compare(_elements[j], v) > 0) ;
         if (i >= j) break;

         tmp = _elements[i];
         _elements[i] = _elements[j];
         _elements[j] = tmp;
         }
     tmp = _elements[i];
     _elements[i] = _elements[right];
     _elements[right] = tmp;
     qsort(left, i-1);
     qsort(i+1, right);
     }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where's the sort code?

Comment: Try calling `strcasecmp` the same way you do in the other comparator. If that doesn't work, post the `operator const char *` code (at least).

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be depending on the return value being -1, 0, or 1 somewhere? (What's the significance of the 10? It's a peculiar value to pick.)

Comment: Your problem can be with cast. It's C style which is not safe. Try using `static_cast<const char*>`